# Refresh Gridview without Refreshing the Whole-page (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, partial-page-refresh

How to refresh the gridview **without refreshing the whole-page**?

I have this code:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3600000">
</asp:Timer>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="250px"  Width="250px">
            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The `Gridview1`'s datasource should be filled from code-behind (based on the real-hour), for example:

```
    Dim DT As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader
    Using myCEConnection As New SqlCeConnection(myCEConnectionString)
        myCEConnection.Open()
        Using myCommand As SqlCeCommand = myCEConnection.CreateCommand()
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule " & _
                                    "WHERE (Hour = '"& Hour(Now) &"')"
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

            DT.Load(reader)
        End Using
        myCEConnection.Close()
    End Using

    Gridview1.DataSource = DT.DefaultView
    Gridview1.DataBind()
```

The `Gridview1` should be refreshed every 1 hour. I tried the code but get nothing. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You had this code running for more than an hour and it did not postback? What have you seen in debugging, with a shorter interval?

Comment: are you looking for data caching for 1 hour?

Comment: Where did you write this code ?  is it on Timer's Tick Event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you write this code on Timer's Tick Event  ?

Ideally it should be on Timer's Tick event. Your timer doesn't have any TICK Event associated.
It should be updated with ontick event (example given below):

```
<asp:Timer ID="timer" runat="server" ontick="timer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

Comment: Two things to point out: since he's using VB.NET, he could have the event wired up using `Handles Timer1.Tick` and, second, I would recommend having the code in a separate method, called by the tick event handler, since he will probably want to call the same code on first Page.Load, as well.

Comment: @Sankalp: Thanks it works. But now why the ticker always reloading the gridview every 1second? I've set the interval to "3600000"...

Comment: Why don't you try by putting your timer control inside the update panel.

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers> <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" /></Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"  Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
    </asp:Timer><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" >..........